# Scalar field density and pressure in FRW metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider a scalar field $\varphi$ with a lagrangian

$\mathscr{L}=\frac{1}{2}g_{ij}\partial^i\varphi\partial^j\varphi$

with a corresponding stress-energy tensor

$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_\varphi}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} = \mathscr{L} g_{\mu\nu} - \partial_\mu\varphi\partial_\nu\varphi$

and considering the Friedmann-Robinson-Walker (FRW) metric

$ds^2=dt^2-a^2(t)(\frac{1}{1-r^2/k^2}dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$.

How can I compute the pressure and density associated to this scalar field? I suppose this is trivial for the density, since this quantity is

$\rho=T_{00}=\frac{1}{2}g_{00}g^{ij}\partial_i \varphi \partial_j \varphi - g_{00}V(\varphi)-\partial_0\varphi\partial_0\varphi=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_0\varphi)^2-V(\varphi)$.

But what about the pressure? In Minkowski metric this quantity should plainly be $p=T_{11}=T_{22}=T_{33}=\frac{1}{2}g_{11}g^{ij}\partial_i\varphi\partial_j\varphi-g_{11}V(\varphi)-\partial_1\varphi\partial_1\varphi$. But I guess that in a metric such as the FRW one the diagonal components of the stress energy tensor are not equal anymore. Hence how should I write the pressure for such scalar field?

Comment: in cartesian FLRW there are no non-diagonal components

Comment: @Kosm indeed, but the diagonal spatial components of the SET will not be equal to each other right?

Comment: they are equal to each other. SET for that scalar field has the form of a perfect fluid.